# AdBannerView weird color overlay

Tags: ios, uiview, iad, adbannerview

I added AdBannerView to my storyboard and it has a weird color overlay (usually green but sometimes red or yellow). It happens on simulator and real device as well.

Screenshots:

http://postimg.org/image/ffsg7am7b/

http://postimg.org/image/nalo44yxn/

The background of AdBannerView is white with alpha 1.0, same as main UIView underneath.

Comment: Try to add the `ADBannerView` programmatically instead of adding it to the storyboard and see what happens then.

Comment: @adam10603 same result

Comment: Even though your app is not a Sprite Kit app and the problem is different, you could try implementing the [same view hierarchy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25825900/3606363) as I did when I had problems with `ADBannerView`. I found that adding it this way changes the `ADBannerView`'s behavior in many ways. Of course replace any `SKView` with `UIView`.

Comment: Basically add two subviews to your main view: one will be the view your app actually uses for it's content from now on, the other is the `ADBannerView`. The "root view" doesn't display anything.